# Apply same style to same type of element of different classes

Tags: css, asp.net, web-applications

```
.class_a {
background-color:lightblue; 
}

.class_b {
background-color: antiquewhite; 
}
```

How do we combine the following 3 lines into one? Thanks.

```
.class_a input[type=text] {width:70px;}
.class_b input[type=text] {width:70px;}
.class_c input[type=text] {width:70px;}
```

Comment: Is this all you want?... http://jsfiddle.net/896280a9/

Comment: Your CSS does **not** represent three elements with different classes. It represents the same element in three different parent classed elements.

Comment: I had tried.class_a input[type=text], .class_b input[type=text], .class_c input[type=text] {width:70px;} it works most of the time, but sometimes it doesn't apply it on Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: yes, it's the same element and its class is selected dynamically programmatically.